# Replacing checkboxes in MS-Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document with a large number of checkboxes spread around the text and I would like to replace all checkboxes with characters.

Example:

```
If checkbox is checked then replace it with "A"
If checkbox is not Checked then replace it with "O"
```

For the time being I can only replace all checkboxes with a letter regardless of their state (checked or unchecked). I need to improve my macro so it recognizes the state of the checkbox and replacing it with the right litteral.

Thanks in advance

```
Sub Checkbox_Replacement()
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
For i = .FormFields.Count To 1 Step -1
With .FormFields(i)
If .Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then
Set Rng = .Range
.Delete
Rng.Text = "A"
End If
End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

Expected Result

```
If checkbox is checked then replace it with "A"
If checkbox is not Checked then replace it with "O"
```

Actual Result

```
All checkboxes are replaced with "A"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the problem was to remove the .Delete

```
Sub Checkbox_Replacement()
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
For i = .FormFields.Count To 1 Step -1
With .FormFields(i)
If .Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then
Set Rng = .Range
If .CheckBox.Value = True Then
Rng.Text = "A"
Else
Rng.Text = "O"
End If
End If
End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a second `If..Else` block to check the condition of the checkbox:

```
If .Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then
Set Rng = .Range
    If .CheckBox.Value = True Then
        Rng.Text = "A"
    Else
        Rng.Text = "O"
    End If
    .Delete
End If
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly when trying to integrate the if..else block in to the code it does no longer work.

Comment: Sub ChkBxClr()
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
For i = .FormFields.Count To 1 Step -1
With .FormFields(i)
If .Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then
Set Rng = .Range
If .CheckBox.Value = True Then
Rng.Text = "A"
Else
Rng.Text = "O"
End If
.Delete
End If
End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
End With
End Sub

Comment: This is the version with integrated else....if but it still doesnt work. I must have missed something.

`Sub ChkBxClr()
Dim i As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
For i = .FormFields.Count To 1 Step -1
With .FormFields(i)
If .Type = wdFieldFormCheckBox Then
Set Rng = .Range
If .CheckBox.Value = True Then
Rng.Text = "A"
Else
Rng.Text = "O"
End If
.Delete
End If
End With
Next
Set Rng = Nothing
End With
End Sub`

Comment: @DimmForSiege, at which line does this error occur? Please give full details.

Comment: There is no referene to line. Please take a look at this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/ItC3sW9.png

Comment: @DimmForSiege, sorry can you step through the code, please?

Comment: It runs until .Delete without actually performing any action and then pops the message. Thanks for helping!

Comment: The code is actually not looping properly. It starts from the bottom replacing the lowest two checkboxes and then stops. Next time I run the macro it will replace the next checkbox and stop again.